# Searching for a "needle" in a two dimnesional "haystack"

Tags: string, algorithm, search

I guess this is one of the most commonly asked interview questions, yet I am unable to solve it in an efficient way(efficient meaning lesser time complexity and use of a suitable Data Structure). 
The problem is this way:
If there is a `m x n matrix` of chars (say haystack) and a given `char` string of length k (the needle) . Write a program to check if the haystack contains the needle. Please note that we need to search the haystack only top to down or left to right.
For example

```
Haystack

ahydsfd
sdflddl
dfdfd
dfdl
uifddffdhc

Needle:
hdffi

Output:
Yes Found!!
```

Comment: What's wrong with searching left-to-right ant top-to-bottom separately?

Comment: I was told by two consecutive interviewers that there is a better approach. I am not sure, "better" in what sense did they mean.

Comment: @n.m.: something to do with cache performance, maybe? Searching top-down is going to be a cache-killer anyway, but you can probably reduce the total number of misses a little bit by mixing it in with the left-to-right searches.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: in "one of the most commonly asked interview questions"?

Comment: @n.m. javacoder990 guesses it's common, based on a sample of two in a row ;-) I don't know, for longer needles you can reduce the complexity compared with naive search, using KMP or whatever. That might be what the interviewer was after, but I don't think it makes any particular difference whether you search in the two directions simultaneously or separately. I can't off-hand think of an algorithmic improvement that relies on doing the two together, hence I guess cache.

Comment: Your sample data doesn't look like a m*n matrix at all. Else my first guess would be, to search for the first letter only in the (m-k)*(n-k) submatrix, which might be pretty irrelevant, if m and n are very big, compared to k.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The naive bruteforce is O(m*n*k). Here are some ideas for optimization.

**Single Search**
Instead of doing a search for horizontals and then another for verticals, do both simultaneously. Every time you find an occurrence of the first letter of the needle look for a horizontal and a vertical match starting at that letter. This won't improve the time complexity, but could halve the time since you'll only look at bad starts once.

**Rare Letters**
Instead of looking for the first letter of the needle, look for the rarest letter which occurs in the needle. This could rule out a lot of the possible matches quickly (though it won't improve the worst-case time complexity). To determine which letters are rarest either scan through the entire board or use random sampling.

**Efficient String Searching Algorithm**
[String searching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) is a well-studied problem and there are several linear-time algorithms such as [Knuth–Morris–Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) and [Boyer–Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm). Using a linear-time string searching algorithm to search each each row and each column reduces the time complexity to O(m*n). This is probably what the interviewers are after.

**Exploit Short Rows**
I notice that not all rows have the same length. When you look for vertical matches, you can stop searching on that row as soon as the needle 'pops out' of the sack, since all needles further along the row will also exit the sack and therefore cannot match.

Comment: Determining the rarest letters by an entire scan would mean, that you visit every cell, which is in most cases the most amount of work, except for a board which contains nearly only - for example - 'd's, and the needle starts with d and consists mostly of 'd's too. But without further knowledge (even distribution of characters, characters token from a text in language x, …) about the text, analyzing the text might take more time than just starting to work. As long as the matrix size isn't known, even a random sample of 100 chars might not be available. Nor do we know, if it's representative.

Answer (score 0):

The brute force method will have worst time complexity of m*n.That is if needle is single character and we start parsing matrix row wise or column wise.

Comment: Of course if needle has length of x character then it can be optimized to have complexity of (m-x-1)*n!

Comment: The problem is with longer needles.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the search of the first char to n-k columns and m-k rows. Once found, 2(k-1) would comparisons are required for the answer.